# How to use onClick event on Card.js component to render Article.js Component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right now i am in Home.js page and i want to render Article.js component/page when user click on particular card (Card.js component). Here is my Home.js code

```
const Home = () => {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts)
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(null)

  const handleClick = () => {
    return <Article />
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h4 className="page-heading">LATEST</h4>
      <div className="card-container">
        {
          posts.map(post => <Card key={post._id} post={post} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} onClick={handleClick} />)
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**ONE MORE PROBLEM :**
How can I send post variable into onClick method? when i send it method is getting called.

Thank You in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @Jackson that you might want to to look into React Router.  But you don't *need* it.  You can conditionally render the `Article` component based on the `currentId`.

A click handler shouldn't return anything.  Instead of returning the `<Article />` from the `onClick` callback, you would use `onClick` to control the `currentId` state.  You can pass a function that sets the `currentId` to the post id based on the `post` variable in your `map` like this: `onClick={() => setCurrentId(post._id)}`.

The `return` for your `Home` component will either render the list of posts or a current post, depending on whether or not you have a `currentId` or just `null`.

```
const Home = () => {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {currentId === null ? (
        // content for list of posts - when currentId is null
        <>
          <h4 className="page-heading">LATEST</h4>
          <div className="card-container">
            {posts.map((post) => (
              <Card
                key={post._id}
                post={post}
                // arrow function takes no arguments but calls `setCurrentId` with this post's id
                onClick={() => setCurrentId(post._id)}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        // content for a single post - when currentId has a value
        <>
          <div
            // setting currentId to null exits the aritcle view
            onClick={() => setCurrentId(null)}
          >
            Back
          </div>
          <Article
            // could pass the whole post
            post={posts.find((post) => post._id === currentId)}
            // or could just pass the id and `useSelector` in the Article component to select the post from redux
            id={currentId}
            // can pass a close callback to the component so it can implement its own Back button
            onClickBack={() => setCurrentId(null)}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You have created a back div to set currentId to null, but what if user insted pressing back div button they press browser's back button? In this case user will not able to go back.

Comment: That's where you would need something like React Router that manages the browser's history.

Comment: Ok i will use React-Router to do that thing. Thanks a lot for your response :)

Comment: Give me one more advice please. Should i send props to Link tag or just take data from redux state?

Comment: Get it from redux.  You should Link to a path like “/article/123”.  In the Article route’s component you would get the param (id=123) from either props or the useParams hook.  Then select the article object from redux based on the id.  You want every page to be able to render the right contents just by the URL so that someone can go directly to the page “/article/123” and everything works.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to use the [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)? As I take it you want to load the post as its own page?

I should also point out that any function passed to `onClick` cannot return anything. The only purpose `return` can serve in an event function is to exit the function early.

Answer (score 1):

To pass in the click hadler the params you want, one could do something like this:

```
      posts.map(post => 
        <Card 
           key={post._id} 
           post={post} 
           onClick={() => handleClick(post)} />
      )
```